# Reservetion parking

Tags: mysql

I have a parking reservation program
with table

| id | sala | tavolo | data | valore | id_prenotazione |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9993 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 9994 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 9995 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 9996 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 9997 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 99933 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99944 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99955 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99966 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99977 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 99938 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99949 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99951 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99962 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99973 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |

and when the booking takes place, 'id_prenotazione' is entered for the booking id and the 'value' from 1 becomes 0.

now the problem is that if I filter from these two dates he occupies me all the 'sala' in that date range and does not stop at just 'sala' with a single 'table' if I change the type of query trying to select only one sala with a table by setting an order by id to have them loaded in order of sala and table eg. from 15-06-2020 to 17-06-2020 I have a reservation then I make another one from 15-06-2022 to 20-06-2022 he does not book me every day but only makes 18-19-20 to finish the 'hall'

the question is: how can I execute the correct query to insert the reservation_id in a date range that occupies only one place and not all of them?

i do this

```
$sql = "select  * from risto_prenota where valore='1' AND id_prenotazione IS NULL and data between '$data_inizio' and '$data_fine' ORDER BY `risto_prenota`.`id` DESC";
$resultSet2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {
$sala =  $row["sala"];
$tavolo=$row["tavolo"];}
```

and then this:

```
$sql = "select  * from risto_prenota where valore='1'  and data between '$data_inizio' and '$data_fine' order by id DESC";
$resultSet2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {
$data_prenota=$row["data"];
//echo $data_prenota;
//echo "</BR>";
$id_pren=$row["id"];

//echo $id_pren;

$query = "UPDATE risto_prenota SET valore = '0', id_prenotazione='$id_prenotazione' where id = '$id_pren' and sala='$sala' and tavolo='$tavolo' ";
if ($link->query($query) === TRUE) {
} else {
}
```

it doesn't work right if i make a reservation from 2022-06-11 to 2022-06-13 it becomes with code up:

| id | sala | tavolo | data | valore | id_prenotazione |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9993 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 0 | 111 |
| 9994 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 0 | 111 |
| 9995 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 0 | 111 |
| 9996 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 9997 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 99933 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99944 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99955 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99966 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99977 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 99938 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99949 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99951 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99962 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99973 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |

then if i make a reservation from 2022-06-11 to 2022-06-15 it becomes:

| id | sala | tavolo | data | valore | id_prenotazione |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9993 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 0 | 111 |
| 9994 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 0 | 111 |
| 9995 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 0 | 111 |
| 9996 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 0 | 112 |
| 9997 | ROMA | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 0 | 112 |
| 99933 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99944 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99955 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99966 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99977 | ROMA2 | 1 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 99938 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-11 | 1 | NULL |
| 99949 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-12 | 1 | NULL |
| 99951 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-13 | 1 | NULL |
| 99962 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-14 | 1 | NULL |
| 99973 | ROMA2 | 2 | 2022-06-15 | 1 | NULL |

skip days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE risto_prenota
JOIN (
    SELECT sala, tavolo
    FROM risto_prenota
    WHERE data BETWEEN @from AND @till
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    HAVING NOT SUM(id_prenotazione IS NOT NULL)
    LIMIT 1
) updated_data USING (sala, tavolo)
SET risto_prenota.id_prenotazione = @id, 
    risto_prenota.valore = 0
WHERE risto_prenota.data BETWEEN @from AND @till;
```

where

- `@from` - booking start date
- `@till` - booking end date
- `@id` - the value to be assigned into `id_prenotazione`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92506e2b73374a128627eda9325a5eb0

PS. The query assumes that there is no "holes" in the dates (in `risto_prenota.data`).

PPS. You may add some ORDER BY into the subquery and provide definite place selection for booking. If the holes are possible than add `AND COUNT(DISTINCT data) = DATEDIFF(@till, @from) + 1` to the HAVING condition of the subquery.

PPPS. I recommend to create stored procedure instead of the query.

Comment: Yes! works but if I have a free place on 14-06 and 15-06 in Rome and a free place on 16-06 in Rome2 he makes me book but doesn't insert my id and doesn't put 0

Comment: @MARTS I cannot understand your words. Update the fiddle, add/edit a block with the data for booking and add desired final data state as a table in a comment.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c0f07015c5345a90f72b0ead5ae5788
13-06-2022 and 14-06-2022

Comment: @MARTS It seems that everything is booked correctly. *13-06-2022 and 14-06-2022* What is wrong with these dates?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b047a12085478d4e53fd987b11102ac
Doesn't run

Comment: did you see it?

Comment: @MARTS This is correct. The query performs booking on the same `(sala, tavolo)` values over whole booking period. IN the last fiddle these dates matches different `(sala, tavolo)`, so these dates are not booked.

Comment: Yes, I know thanks. is there a way that would then allow me to occupy them?

Comment: @MARTS Of course. If you does not need in `(sala, tavolo)` to be the same then you may do not use `updated_data` subquery. Simply enumerate the rows over the date in CTE and book/update rows with row_number() = 1.

Comment: Can you write me the code? I am still a beginner. Thank you really much

Comment: @MARTS https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1182361b6eba25db1b9379a8b1ced6fc

Comment: ok this is perfect but can i use without a SP? the code is in a php page

Comment: $enumerate_rows="SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY data  ORDER BY sala, tavolo) AS rn FROM risto_prenota WHERE data BETWEEN $data_inizio AND $data_fine AND id_prenotazione IS NULL";
$resultSet2 = mysqli_query($db, $enumerate_rows); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {
$check_completeness="SELECT SUM(rn = 1) = DATEDIFF($data_inizio , $data_fine) + 1 AS checking_result";
 
   $query="UPDATE risto_prenota JOIN $enumerate_rows USING (id) CROSS JOIN $check_completeness SET risto_prenota.id_prenotazione = $id_prenotazione, risto_prenota.valore = 0 WHERE rn = 1";

Comment: if ($link->query($query) === TRUE) {
} else {
} 
}

Comment: I try to do this but doesn't work

Comment: @MARTS *can i use without a SP?* of course. *the code is in a php page* What is the difference between query execution and SP execution? none...

Comment: Yes but when i try doesn't work, is it right write: $query= " your code"; ?

Comment: @MARTS Compare first and last fiddles, pay attention to the parameters providing (UDV in first cove and LV in the last one).

Comment: $enumerate_rows="SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY data ORDER BY sala, tavolo) AS rn FROM risto_prenota WHERE data BETWEEN $data_inizio AND $data_fine";
$check_completeness ="SELECT SUM(rn = 1) = DATEDIFF($data_inizio,$data_fine) + 1 AS checking_result FROM $enumerate_rows";
$query="UPDATE risto_prenota JOIN enumerate_rows USING (id) CROSS JOIN $check_completeness  SET risto_prenota.id_prenotazione = $id_prenotazione, risto_prenota.valore = '0' WHERE rn = '1'  AND $check_completeness.checking_result;";

Comment: I do like this but doesn't work :( where am i wrong?